# xmlsettings.DoNotEscapeUriAttributes not working

Tags: xml

I am trying to serialize XML that has URLs in the attributes
I discovered the XMLsetting.DoNotEscapeUriAttributes  but it does not seem to change the output`

```
            XmlWriterSettings xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings()
           // seems like the right setting for me
            xmlSettings.DoNotEscapeUriAttributes = true;
            everywhere says this is how to create xmlwriter with settings
             XmlWriter tw = XmlTextWriter.Create(memStream, xmlSettings);
            // next line throws exception as thexmlwritersettings is ereadonly??
            tw.Settings.DoNotEscapeUriAttributes = true;
            serializer.Serialize(tw, rss, nameSpace);
```

`
any other way to prevent my URLs in XML attributes from getting escaped?

Comment: Tell us what software you're using (I think I've worked it out, but why did you make me waste my time doing that?) And tell us what your input, actual output, and desired output are.

Comment: this code is written in  .netcore 3.1   
inputurl:https://video.internetvideoarchive.net/video.mp4?cmd=6&amp;fmt=4&amp;customerid=857396&amp;publishedid=198496&amp;e=1652097630&amp;sub=Xumo&amp;videokbrate=8000&amp;h=fd1cd147d8ba5daf975429ff4af0275
output:https://video.internetvideoarchive.net/video.mp4?cmd=6&amp;fmt=4&amp;customerid=857396&amp;publishedid=198496&amp;e=1652097630&amp;sub=Xumo&amp;videokbrate=8000&amp;h=fd1cd147d8ba5daf975429ff4af0275